# Why did my armature disappear?

Tags: armature, bones

I built an armature. After completing it, I moved it to another layer. Now all my bones are gone.

If you look at the [video](https://youtu.be/dT6JlH-b9rw), you see the mech on one layer, and as I select the layer where I moved the bones to, they are not visible.  In the mech layer, I see the black lines connecting everything, but now I can not pose the mech as I have no access to the bones.

In the [video](https://youtu.be/dT6JlH-b9rw), I go through each mode and use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>, but nothing is happening.

Where are the bones?

Comment: Have you checked the bone layer in the Skeleton Tab?

Comment: ah, yup, there they are.  only had blender for 2 weeks, and his is my 1st 3D program, so have lots to learn still.  now i know.  thanx

Comment: @Immelmann could you please accept the answer if it helped you?

Answer (score 3):

The bones layers are different from the mesh layers. To find your bone layers, you select your armature from the outliner then under the skeleton menu under the properties panel you will find the bones layers there.

Answer (score 0):

Had this happen in 2.8, and realised that my problem was the buttons for hiding/showing things are now hidden until you enable them. To find them, click on the filter in the top-right corner of the Outliner, and turn them back on as you like. You should then be able to show/hide specific things as before. Screenshot attached.
[image]